# What's the correct pattern to change parent state inside a child state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Imagine I have a page "Parent" which conditionally renders a div "Child". 
On the click of a button, "Child" opens. To close "Child" one has to click in a X button inside it.

This is how I would do it and in my opinion it looks clean.

```
const Parent = (props) => {
  const [childVisible, setChildVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      {childVisible && <Child close={setChildVisible.bind(false)} />}
      <button onClick={setChildVisible.bind(true)}>
        Open Child
      </button>
    </>
  )
}

const Child = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Im Child</p>
      <button onClick={props.close()}> X </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Since react v16.13.0 react has introduced a warning `Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.` and it seems I can't do this anymore.

What's the correct pattern now? I would rather not have a state in both components stating the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Call back was not properly added .You could do like this `onClick={props.close}`

While use `onClick={props.close()}` like this. close() function run on child mount instead of click event

```
const Child = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Im Child</p>
      <button onClick={props.close}> X </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```